# Traefik v2.1.4 - How to create a static route and redirect to a specific host and port

Tags: docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik, forwarding

I'm a beginner with Traefik v2.1.4. I'm using in a docker container. I'm trying to set up a static route. I found some examples using the toml configuration file.

```
[providers]
[providers.file]
[http]
    [http.routers]
        [http.routers.netdata]
            rule = "Host(`netdata.my-domain.com`)"
            service = "netdata"
            entrypoint=["http"]

    [http.services]
          [http.services.netdata.loadbalancer]
            [[http.services.netdata.loadbalancer.servers]]
              url = "https://192.168.0.2:19999"
```

Following this example I would like to convert it to docker labels of my docker-compose.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1.4
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=false"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsresolver.acme.email=my-email@domain.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      # global redirect to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.middlewares=redirect-to-https" 
      # dashboard
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.my-domain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=admin"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=letsresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.admin.basicauth.users=user:hash-passwordXXX"

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"


 networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: network
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to **use 2 providers together: `file` and `docker`**.

Your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.2.1
    command: traefik --configFile=/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - ./routes.yml:/etc/traefik/routes.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

   # your services go here ...
```

Your `traefik.yml`:

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80

providers:
  docker: {}

  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/routes.yml
    watch: true
```

Your `routes.yml`:

```
http:
  routers:
    hello:
      rule: PathPrefix(`/hello`)
      service: hello@docker
      rule: PathPrefix(`/world`)"
      service: world@docker
```

These are only examples, don't use them in production environment directly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is no docker label mentioned to specify url (in https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/routing/providers/docker/#routers). And I tried to use url instead of port, but it does not work.
So I suggest to use the file provider (https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/providers/file/).

#### suggeston for implementation:

update your config with:

```
services:
  ...
  traefik:
    ...
    command:
      ...
      - "--providers.file.directory=/path/to/dynamic/conf"
    config:
    - source: redirect.toml
      target: /path/to/dynamic/conf/redirect.toml
    ...

...
configs:
  redirect.toml:
    file: redirect.toml
```

and create redirect.toml with your redirection (as in your example).

Of course you can also bindmount the config into the container, or create your own traefik image containing the config, or ...

---

In case you want to work with labels, you can start a service which redirects with socat

```
services:
  ...

  netdata:
    image: alpine/socat
    command: tcp-listen:80,fork,reuseaddr tcp-connect:192.168.0.2:19999
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.netdata.rule: Host(`netdata.my-domain.com`)
        traefik.http.services.netdata_srv.loadbalancer.server.port: 80
        # hm, and probably tell to forward as https, ...
```